# Android internal storage shared by selected apps

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for iOS, Android, and UWP and am looking for a way to have a set of files (GBs of photos, videos, documents, etc.) shared between apps that I develop, but not accessible by other apps. For iOS, adding my apps to an App Group will create a shared container and for UWP, I can specify a publisher cache folder in the app manifest. But, I have not been able to find a way to do the same thing on Android.

When I look in the [Android developer documentation for files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files), I see that for internal storage

> Files saved here are accessible by only your app

and for external storage

> It's world-readable, so files saved here may be read outside of your control.

I am looking for something in between: where, like external storage, files are accessible by multiple apps; but like internal storage, files are accessible only by apps that I develop. Ideally, the files would be deleted when the apps are uninstalled. Does a mechanism exist for that?

Comment: You want to look at the FileProvider api. It will let you specify which apps can access which files. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#Permissions

Comment: `GBs of photos, videos, documents, etc` Be carefull. Not all devices have GB's of storage in internal memory.